# Why Adobe forums forbidden?

Tags: flash, adobe, forums

For me and most of my friends from Ukraine Adobe forums are forbidden.

For example visiting page like: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/675241
will cause:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /thread/675241 on this server.
```

I can still view forums from google cache.
Any ideas?

Stan

Comment: I don't think this is something you should be asking us. We're not Adobe. See if you can reach their support page and contact them from there.

Comment: Yeap, looks like adobe blocked SPAM with huge range. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/825974

Answer (score 1):

Try removing old cookies from the forum you're trying to access.

Comment: Just did clear cookie in IE via Ctrl+Shif+Del (Select All). Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i've experienced the same issue, and you can resolve it by removing all cookies and sessions from your browser.
Have you tried accessing the page with another browser?

Comment: Tried to remove cookies. Didn't help. And opera, IE, FF.

Comment: Strange... try changing your ip if you can, by rebooting your router.